# Repeat rows at the bottom as footer in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Microsoft Excel Page setup, we can set rows to repeat at the top and at the left. I'd like to know if is there any way, or is there any trick/hack to repeat rows at the bottom of each page as like footer?

Answer (score 0):

Other than physically designing a worksheet with faux footers and using a formula to repeat "bottom rows", there is not "repeat bottom row" ([source](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/advanced-excel-reporting-printing-features-repeated-headers-footers-c-sharp-net-6#:%7E:text=MS%20Excel%20does%20not%20have,a%20footer%20on%20every%20page.)). However, you can explicitly add a footer.

[image]

Comment: The Custom Footer menu has very little to offer.